# What's the term for a company email address containing the employee's name?

Tags: terminology

What do you call an email address like michaelwong@companyname.com that contains the employee's names, rather than a collective email like  media@companyname.com or ir@companyname.com?

I need the *named* email addresses, when the collective email fails to forward my emails to the germane people!

Many non native English speakers don't understand what I mean. I must write like three hundred words to explain my request for their *named company email address*. Some of them are baffled, and think I'm requesting their personal email address like gmail, which I'm not!

Comment: If you were to say the same to me, I'd have no idea what the hell you're talking about, and I'm a native speaker.

Comment: Can I have your business email address please (as opposed to can I have your personal email address).

Comment: I know what you're asking for, but I don't think there's a concise term for it.  "NAMED company email address" is **definitely not** it.  Also:  Depending on the individual's role in the company, they may not be provided with an email, or they may not be allowed to share it.  It may only be used for internal communications.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to forward"?  Email distribution lists do not generally have logic that can fail to forward messages to the individual emails in the distribution list.  There may be spam filters but those would generally apply to every email account in the company.   If you are sending emails that are getting flagged by spam filters or that people aren't bothering to open, you probably want to address that issue rather than blaming the email address

Comment: Perhaps they have group email addresses because too many people are demanding their direct email address? On the other hand, if the person you're trying to reach isn't in the group then perhaps you aren't sending to the right group.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just ask for it the same way you described it in the post?  Something like:  "What is your 'FirstnameLastname@company.com' email address?" or something that would make more sense for them, but you get my point

Comment: Please don't edit your question into shouty rants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps a bit clunky - but asking

> Do you have an individual email address at your company, where a message sent to that email address only appears in your inbox?

might avoid confusion.

Answer (score 14):

When dealing with phone numbers, "direct" is the used adjective for this. A direct phone number is the phone number that goes straight to your desk and bypasses reception.

People might still understand your intention when you use "direct" for an e-mail address; but this is not strictly defined at the moment.

Comment: +1. I think anyone sensible will understand what "direct" means in the email context, especially if you introduce the problem as "I have your team email address a@b.com, but do you have a direct email address where I can reach you individually?"

Answer (score 8):

> *What do you call an email address like michaelwong@shkp.com that contains the employee's names, rather than a collective email...*

Question is: why do you need that specific <sup>note</sup> information?

If someone is providing an email address for correspondence, then that is the email you should be using for directing your communication. There are several good reasons these "group" emails are created, for example: to be able to receive and respond to support request by whoever is handling the support functionality at that point of time, instead of depending on any individual's availability. Also, having an alias-based email address helps to abstract the individual handling the responsibility and allow the function to run smoothly, even if that individual is no longer associated / working for that role / organization.

Bottom line: If you have received an email address through proper channel, feel free to use it - it usually does not matter if it belongs to an individual or an alias.

---

*[Note:] IANAL, but email address is considered PII, so there may be situations where providing email of directed individuals is simply not an option.*

Comment: I don't disagree with your views regarding corporate email practices - but your answer does not seem to address what such an email address might be called, but rather whether it is appropriate to even ask for it. Which I find is an entirely different question.

Comment: @morsor Frame challenges can also be a valid answer.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: OK, fair enough

Comment: _"email address is considered PII"_ **Personal** email address, yes. Business email address, no. The existence of the email address implies the willingness for people to know the email address, which in a business context means that it can be shared with involved parties. If I share my colleague's work email address, I may have made a professional faux pas (depending on context) but I did not break any privacy law. If you object to having your name in an email address, the solution is not to hide the existing email address, but rather to have it removed altogether.

Comment: @Flater fair enough, I do not have enough expertise to comment on personal vs business emails in this context. That said, as mentioned in the example in my answer, having names in email address is not the problem, problem is, if someone is providing an alias email address for communication - there is most likely a very valid reason behind that (even when email addresses are meant to be shared and are shared widely). Looking for individual's business email thereafter may not be very useful.

Comment: There likely is a reason the individual is asking emails to be sent to a group email rather than their personal work email, the reason, is not likely going to be shared with anyone outside of the company @ElVaf - You can only ping one person in a comment so the author of this answer wasn’t notified of your comment

Answer (score 4):

“Your individual work email address, not a group or alias”

Comment: Non-native speakers are likely to be "baffled, and think [OP is] requesting their PERSONAL email address like gmail, which [OP is] not!"

Comment: "Individual work email" would clear this up. But I would understand what is meant.